# standard deviation (and percentiles) of multiple arrays of the same dimension in R

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have several different arrays of the same dimension. Is there a way to find the standard deviation, mean, and some percentiles of all the arrays? My final result should be one array with the same dimension as each of the individual arrays.

I tried the following it clearly doesn't work

```
m1 <- array(runif(8), dim = c(2, 2, 2))
m2 <- array(runif(8), dim = c(2, 2, 2))
m3 <- array(runif(8), dim = c(2, 2, 2))

sd(m1, m2, m3)
```

Comment: What do you meant by `some percentiles`

Comment: By percentiles, I meant taking the quantiles. For example for the 90th percentile it will be computed as the following: p90 <- apply(array(c(m1, m2, m3), dim = c(2, 2, 2, 3)), c(1, 2, 3), function(x) quantile(x, c(0.90)))

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a single `array` and use `apply` to loop over the dimensions and get the `sd`

```
out <- apply(array(c(m1, m2, m3), dim = c(2, 2, 2, 3)), c(1, 2, 3), sd)
```

-checking the output

```
> sd(c(m1[1], m2[1], m3[1]))
[1] 0.1623589
> out[1]
[1] 0.1623589
```

---

Use the same method for `mean`

```
out2 <- apply(array(c(m1, m2, m3), dim = c(2, 2, 2, 3)), c(1, 2, 3), mean)
```